# Aligning HTML table header with table data rows

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have some HTML code that generates an HTML table with header and data rows.  The header columns do not line up with the data columns.

I got this code from an example I found online.  I want the header cell widths to match the data cell widths of the table.

Here is the below code is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tee3n/.

HTML

```
<div class="scrollableContainer">
  <div class="scrollingArea">
   <table class="cruises scrollable">
     <thead>
        <tr>
         <th><div class="name">Name</div></th>
         <th><div class="operator">Operator</div></th>
         <th><div class="began">Began operation</div></th>
         <th><div class="tonnage">Tonnage</div></th>
         <th><div class="status">Status</div></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="name">Name of ship</div></td>
          <td><div class="operator">Who operates</div></td>
          <td><div class="began">Began service when</div></td>
          <td><div class="tonnage">How big</div></td>
          <td><div class="status">Current status</div></td>                        
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="name">Name of ship</div></td>
          <td><div class="operator">Who operates</div></td>
          <td><div class="began">Began service when</div></td>
          <td><div class="tonnage">How big</div></td>
          <td><div class="status">Current status</div></td>                        
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="name">Name of ship</div></td>
          <td><div class="operator">Who operates</div></td>
          <td><div class="began">Began service when</div></td>
          <td><div class="tonnage">How big</div></td>
          <td><div class="status">Current status</div></td>                        
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="name">Name of ship</div></td>
          <td><div class="operator">Who operates</div></td>
          <td><div class="began">Began service when</div></td>
          <td><div class="tonnage">How big</div></td>
          <td><div class="status">Current status</div></td>                        
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="name">Name of ship</div></td>
          <td><div class="operator">Who operates</div></td>
          <td><div class="began">Began service when</div></td>
          <td><div class="tonnage">How big</div></td>
          <td><div class="status">Current status</div></td>                        
        </tr><tr>
          <td><div class="name">Name of ship</div></td>
          <td><div class="operator">Who operates</div></td>
          <td><div class="began">Began service when</div></td>
          <td><div class="tonnage">How big</div></td>
          <td><div class="status">Current status</div></td>                        
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="name">Name of ship</div></td>
          <td><div class="operator">Who operates</div></td>
          <td><div class="began">Began service when</div></td>
          <td><div class="tonnage">How big</div></td>
          <td><div class="status">Current status</div></td>                        
        </tr></tr><tr>
          <td><div class="name">Name of ship</div></td>
          <td><div class="operator">Who operates</div></td>
          <td><div class="began">Began service when</div></td>
          <td><div class="tonnage">How big</div></td>
          <td><div class="status">Current status</div></td>                        
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="name">Name of ship</div></td>
          <td><div class="operator">Who operates</div></td>
          <td><div class="began">Began service when</div></td>
          <td><div class="tonnage">How big</div></td>
          <td><div class="status">Current status</div></td>                        
        </tr>
        </tr><tr>
          <td><div class="name">Name of ship</div></td>
          <td><div class="operator">Who operates</div></td>
          <td><div class="began">Began service when</div></td>
          <td><div class="tonnage">How big</div></td>
          <td><div class="status">Current status</div></td>                        
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><div class="name">Name of ship</div></td>
          <td><div class="operator">Who operates</div></td>
          <td><div class="began">Began service when</div></td>
          <td><div class="tonnage">How big</div></td>
          <td><div class="status">Current status</div></td>                        
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table.cruises { 
    font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    cellspacing: 0; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width: 99.9%;    
    }
  table.cruises th, table.cruises td { 
    border-right: 1px solid #999; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999; 
    width: 20%;
    }
  table.cruises th { background: #aab; }
  table.cruises td { background: #eee; }

  div.scrollableContainer { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 80%; 
    padding-top: 1.7em; 
    margin: 40px;    
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: black;
    }
  div.scrollingArea { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 240px; 
    overflow: auto; 
    }
  table.scrollable thead tr {
    left: 0; top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    }

  table.cruises .name     { width: 20%; }
  table.cruises .operator { width: 20%; }
  table.cruises .began    { width: 20%; text-align:center; }
  table.cruises .tonnage  { width: 20%; text-align:center; }
  table.cruises .status   { width: 20%; }
```

Why is the header not aligning up with the data columns underneath?

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I ended up using datatables plugin (datatables.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using datatables plugin (datatables.net).

Answer (score 1):

Check your CSS:

```
  table.scrollable thead th tr {
    left: 0; top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    }
```

I added the `th`.

Also, removed `padding-top: 1.7em;` from the

```
 div.scrollableContainer { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 80%; 
    padding-top: 1.7em; 
    margin: 40px;    
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: black;
    }
```

to remove the black space at the top.  It should work (tested in Chrome).

Comment: Thanks Sable Foste but that is not what i am looking for it, I want the header to be fixed.

Comment: Then I am confused... in you fiddle, it looks like you have what you want, only the columns are not aligned with the table body.  They are off by the width of the scroll bar.  Are you wanting to pop the scrollbar off to the left of the whole table?

Comment: If you open my fiddle on IE7... that's what i want. But it doesn't work on IE8 or IE9. On IE8 and IE9 the thead colums doesn't align with tbody columns.